# Did Kiyoshi have an injured knee even before being seriously injured by Kirisaki Daīchi High?

Tags: kuroko-no-basket

In *Kuroko no Basuke*, Kiyoshi missed the first half of the year because he was undergoing rehab due to his injury against Kirisaki Daīchi High in the final match of Prelims the year before.

However, on rewatching Episode 8 of Season 2, where the flashback of the previous year's journey and Kiyoshi are focused on, I noticed that Kiyoshi looks down at his legs a number of times throughout the episode, even before the injury.

The most specific scene however is ~15mins into the episode, just after Hyuga compliments Kiyoshi on his dunk, we see Kiyoshi wincing and see his leg is quivering. This seems like a stretch that he injured his leg twice in the match.
More probable (my theory, anyway) is that he was carrying this injury before the tournament and didn't tell the others because he didn't want the team to pull out without him in the first year itself.

**TL;DR - Was Kiyoshi injured before his match against Kirisaki Daīchi High or it is canon he had another injury?**

Answer (score 1):

After watching the episode, I think Kiyoshi started having the injury on his legs for playing too much. He may have known about it because he is tall, thus he will likely to injure his legs more than average size person (I read an article about tall basketball players are more prone to injury).

So yes, he was injured before his match against Kirisaki Daīchi High, and Makoto Hanamiya made it worse by injuring him.

Answer (score 1):

Well, he technically was but it wasn't that serious until Hanamiya made it worse. It's like after sports, sometimes you might have pulled a muscle or something which is considered kind of minor. From the strain Hanamiya was giving Seirin, it was possible that he got a sort of pulled muscle or something during the game and Hanamiya noticed this and, concluding that he was weaker in that area, injured Kiyoshi even more.

Answer (score 1):

From what we've seen, Kiyoshi clearly had some issues with his knee before Hanamiya injured him. However, we have **no canonical evidence** to tell us how serious that injury was. We know it wasn't bad enough to keep him from playing, but we don't know if it was something he'd been dealing with for years or if it had just started in that game.

Answer (score 1):

As I watch it again, maybe it was caused by overworking. When a flashback happened while in the middle of the match between Yosen and Seirin, while he was practicing back then in Shoei Middle School, he said to his playmates that he would protect them while dunking the ball.

Maybe it is like the case of Kise as of overworking for the match of Toou. But as slightly different, Kise injured his foot while Kiyoshi injured his legs.

That's my theorem.